# How to deserialize tag data using spaCy's new DocBin() class

Tags: python, serialization, nlp, spacy

I am attempting to save Doc data and attributes to binary using the new DocBin() class in spacy

I have saved data using pickle before but am looking for a more efficient method.

def serialize_to_disk():

```
doc_bin = DocBin(attrs=["LEMMA", "ENT_IOB", "ENT_TYPE", "POS", "TAG"], store_user_data=True)
for doc in nlp.pipe(ff):
    # print(doc.is_parsed) this DOES produce parsed docs
    doc_bin.add(doc)
bytes_data = doc_bin.to_bytes()
print(type(bytes_data))
with open("bytes/test", "wb") as binary_file:
    binary_file.write(bytes_data)
```

def deserialize_from_disk():

```
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
with open("bytes/test", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
doc_bin = DocBin().from_bytes(data)
docs = list(doc_bin.get_docs(nlp.vocab))
# this list does not have the tag data. Why?
return docs
```

when I call doc.is_parsed on the deserialized list, it returns False. Before serialization, this returns True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only marked as parsed if the attributes for a dependency parse (`HEAD` and/or `DEP`) are included in the attributes list. `is_parsed` is just for the dependency parse, not the whole analysis. There's also `is_tagged` for the tagger, if that's what you're looking for.